# could not find the coorect provider above the home widget

Tags: function, class, flutter, exception, provider

Hello guys i faced that problem, i don't really know how to solve it, I tried many things and saw many posts but the problem persists.

the code is too long so here is the most important part

i'll need in this class the provider (to call a function in the UpdateMarkers class) and when i go to the other page i'll use it to get a set of markers

thank you for helping me :)

```js
class grpTile extends StatelessWidget{
final String grp_nom;
final String grp_chemin;
grpTile({@required this.grp_nom, u/required this.grp_chemin});
u/override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ChangeNotifierProvider<UpdateMarkers>(
builder:(_) =>UpdateMarkers(),



Provider.of<UpdateMarkers>(context).UpdateusersLocation(grp_chemin);

Navigator.push(context,

MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MapVoyagePage (g)));
```

Comment: please provide the whole class where you are putting the `ChangeNotifier` in the tree of widgets, and the whole code where you are calling it, as the details presented now don't suffice to see the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way is place `ChangeNotifierProvider` higher than necessary 
Without knowing your app structure, you can init in `main()` 
You can reference official example https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple#changenotifierprovider

```
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => UpdateMarkers(),
      child: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```